# Flutter Duplicate items and does not remove

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add elements in list whenever I press the round `RoundIcnBt` and delete when pressed again  but it adds duplicate items and do not remove when the button is pressed again is there any other way to do this pls suggest what I want to is when a user presses the button the data should be stored to list and when user again press the same button item should be delete:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mdi/mdi.dart';

class MyListEX extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyListEX({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyListEXState createState() => _MyListEXState();
}

class _MyListEXState extends State<MyListEX> {
  List l = [];
  var distl = [];
  final List<int> rollNo = [
    2016239001,
    2016239002,
    2016239003,
    2016239004,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    offset: const Offset(3.0, 3.0),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 2.0,
                  ),
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    blurRadius: 0.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                child: ListTile(
                  trailing: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RoundIcnBt(
                        icon: Mdi.alphaPCircle,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            l.add([
                              {
                                {rollNo[index]},
                                true
                              }
                            ]);
                            print(distl = l.toSet().toList(growable: true));
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
                  title: Text('${rollNo[index]}'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added an answer using default `IconButton` check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` type variable to add and remove elements.

So, change your `List l = [];` to `Set l = {};`.

Now, in your `setState` inside the button, you can do this,

```
setState(() {
  if (l.contains(rollNo[index])) {
    // l already contains this roll number, so you can remove it
    l.remove(rollNo[index]);
  } else {
    // l doesn't contains this roll number, so you can add it
    l.add(rollNo[index]);
  }
});
```

Now, `l` will maintain which roll numbers you have selected at any point of time.

Here is the working code. I have also added a small green tick icon beside the `Text` to show you whether a roll number has been added or not.

Paste bin link to full working code - [Code](https://pastebin.com/wGmti7pG)

Comment: thankyou so much it solved my problem and also thanks for for that additional green tick

Answer (score 0):

Make List rollNo not final, so you can add and remove from your list...

Comment: but i am adding   elements in another list named as l